# Image of a set of measure zero by a Lipschitzian function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Lipsichitzian functions are defined the following way:

> $f:A\subset R^n \rightarrow R^n$ where $\exists K \geq 0$ such that $||f(x)-f(y)||\leq K||x-y||$

Given this, proove the following:

> Given a set $Z \subset A$ such that $m(Z)=0$ prove that it's a suficient condition that $f$ being Lipsichitzian is a suficient condition for $m(f(Z))=0$

For this, I've done the following proof:

$f:A\subset R^n \rightarrow R^n$ a Lipsichitzian function and $Z \subset A$ with $m(Z)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $m(f(Z))=0$

First, let's proove that $f$ is continuous:

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \ \ \  \exists \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{K} \gt0 $ such that if $||x-y|| \lt \delta$ then $||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq K||x-y|| \lt \epsilon$ therefore $f$ is continuous. Note that if $K=0$ then $f$ is a constant function so thats a trivial case.

We know that $m(Z)=0 \Rightarrow \exists G \in \tau_u$ such that $Z \subset G$ and $m(G) \leq \epsilon$. We also know that $G=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i$ with $I_i$ disjointed intervals.

Given an interval $I=[\textbf{a},\textbf{b}]$ we know that $m(I)=vol(I) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} |b_i - a_i|$. Then, $m(f(I))= \Pi_{i=1}^n (f(b_i)-f(a_i)) \leq \Pi_{i=1}^n K (b_i - a_i) = K^n \Pi_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i) = K^n m(I)$

With this property we do the following:

$m(f(Z)) \leq m(f(\cup_{k=1}^n I_k)) = m(\cup_{k=1}^nf(I_k)) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m(f(I_k)) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} K^n m(I_k) = K^nm(G)=K^n \epsilon$

From where taking $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ we get that $m(f(Z))=0$

I'm not sure about the proof and I'm looking for someone to verify it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an issue with the restriction to boxes. I suspect that what you write there for $m(f(I))$ would require an additional assumption, like $f$ factoring into functions of $1$ coordinate. However, the idea works and can be done more cleanly by saying $G=\cup_{k=1}^\infty B(x_k,r_k)$, where the sum of the volume of the balls is less than $\varepsilon$. Then $m(f(G))\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(f(B(x_k,r_k))\lesssim K^n\varepsilon$. You need to be a bit careful with the constant, as you need to express the volume bound in terms of the $r_k$.

Comment: And what about taking the image of the points $\textbf{a}_i, \textbf{b}_i$ as $\textbf{a}_i=(0,0,...,0,a_i,0,...,0), \textbf{b}_i=(0,0,...,0,b_i,0,...,0)$? Then the same argument would apply and I wouldn't have to worry about the function $f$ factoring into 1 coordintae functions

Comment: How exactly do you prove $m(f(I))=\prod_{k=1}^n (f(b_k)-f(a_k))$? Even in dimension $n=1$, consider $I=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=|x|$. Then the RHS is $0$, but the LHS is $1$. This actually shows that even if $f$ factors into coordinate functions, this can still fail.

Comment: My idea was that as $f$ is continuous, $f(I)$ has to be an interval of the type $[f(a_1), f(b_1)]\times [f(a_2), f(b_2)]\times \cdots \times [f(a_n), f(b_n)]$ therefore its volume must be the product of those differences. However this was by intuition so might be wrong

Comment: Indeed. For my example where the function is the absolute value, $f(I)=[0,1]$ and $[f(-1),f(1)]=\{1\}$. Your intuition about $f$ being continuous is almost implying this is almost correct in some sense. Since $f$ restricted to any coordinate is also continuous, minima and maxima are attained, but not necessarily at the endpoints of the domain. That's why this does not work.

Comment: So you are sugesting to do a similar thing but using open balls instead of intervals right? then you know that the diameter of the balls is bounded by $K$ in a way right?

Comment: Yup. Exactly. Because you don't need to deal with the factorization into coordinate intervals.

Comment: Okay, i get it now. Thanks for the help!!